# python Telegram bot payment issue, example paymentbot.py with stripe sevicer

Tags: python, stripe-payments, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using python telegram bot,testing the example "[paymentbot.py](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/paymentbot.py)" through the Stride provider. I already set everything up and followed the steps of the documentation. I made a test payment with the "test card" expecting to see the invoice in the stride **test mode** dashboard, but it never appears.

The transaction is said as "successfully" in telegram, but never reaches Stripe, in the log of stripe is written:

-your account authorised the telegram application

But not any payment is logged, received or displayed. In addition, if I make a payment through other channels (no telegram) it succeed and log.

-The payment of xxxxxx for x euros has succeeded

Do I need to add an api, a http request, or something else to the example in order to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I have discovered that in TEST mode the telegram API seems not to do any request to Stripe, in contrast with other test applications. But the payments are working on LIVE, so it is not a big issue but a missing desirable feature.

More about it, can be found here:

https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2674